# Eclipse can't find JDK source

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I'm helping my friend debug his applet with Eclipse. I stepped through a few lines easily, until an error came up saying that the source is not found for `AppletViewerPanel.class`. I even added the src.zip that came with JDK but it's still not found. What can I do to continue debugging, or to bypass this? I tried stepping over instead of stepping into but nothing changes

I have JRE 6 Update 29. Same version for JDK

Comment: Why is it a problem that you can't see source? Eclipse debugger should keep debugging. You can still "step return" back to the calling class, and then continue stepping through the source which you can see.

Comment: 'Cause weird things happen when I step return. The step buttons get disabled, same with the resume button. The only thing I can do is to suspend or terminate the applet

Answer (score 0):

Clean your project and retry, if not restart eclipse. Seems to be just a random missing file. Happens to me every so oftern.